# How to Insert JsonArray values to Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Json array with city names ("pa") and city names ("tan") in it. I want to add them to the Room database but the app crashes without any error, possibly my inset operati,on is blocking the UI thread

this is how I iterate throught the Json array and get the values

```
try {
            JSONArray citiesJsonArray = new JSONArray(unzippedCitiesString);
            Cities cities = new Cities();


            for (int i = 0; i < citiesJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject data = citiesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String cityNumber = data.getString("pa");
                String cityName = data.getString("tar");

                cities.setCityName(cityName);
                cities.setCityCode(cityNumber);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I set them to the Cities Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "cities")
public class Cities {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "_cityname")
    private String cityName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "_citycode")
    private String cityCode;

.... getters and setters here
```

this is my CitiesDao

```
@Dao
public interface CitiesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cities")
    List<Banks> getAllCities();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cities where _cityname LIKE  :cityName")
    Banks findByName(String cityName);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cities where _citycode LIKE  :cityCode")
    Banks findByCode(int cityCode);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from cities")
    int countCities();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void addCity(Cities cities);


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(Cities... cities);

    @Delete
    void delete(Cities cities);

    @Update
    void update(Cities cities);


}
```

this is my db

```
@Database(entities = {Cities.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "DB";

    public abstract CitiesDao citiesDao();


}
```

and finally I initialize my db inside the onCreate method of MainActivity

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyDatabase.class, MyDatabase.DB_NAME).build();
```

I tried to populate the database in the try catch block like:

database.CitiesDao().insertAll(cities) after I set the values but it crashed without any log. Can't find the solution

Edit: 
I resolved the exception by initializing the db at my base Application but I dont know how to populate the db with the json array data

Comment: `"but the app crashes without any error,"` - you mean no stacktrace on the logcat? how come?

Comment: "the app crashes without any error" -- either it is not crashing, there is a stack trace in LogCat, or you caught the exception and failed to log the exception to LogCat.

Comment: It was a logcat malfunction I get unable to start activity at where I was trying to initialize the Database

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: I solved the issue but I cant insert json array data to my room

Answer (score 0):

Try This I had Same Issue

After Initialize DB use `AsyncTask` Or `RxJava` Background operation or New thread to avoid UI block

```
  database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyDatabase.class, 
 MyDatabase.DB_NAME).build();

new DatabaseAsync().execute();



private class DatabaseAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //Perform pre-adding operation here.
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            database.CitiesDao().insertAll(cities) 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            //To after addition operation here.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, should I iterate through my jsonArray inside onPreExecute then right?

Comment: Inside doing background do iteration please

Comment: the thing is I get unable to start activity where I'm trying to initialize database in my onCreate method

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: same issue, still cant create activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163718/discussion-between-sam-and-ege-kuzubasioglu).